# Updating listview containing the name of folders in external storage in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-external-storage

I have a `ListView` showing the names of all the folders of external storage. I want to refresh or update the `ListView` automatically when new folder is created or deleted by my application.But it never gets updated automatically until I open that layout file again. I'm using Get Files () method to get files and then view them in `ListView`.What should i do now? 
any help is appreciated thanks in advance
i am using this code to show all folders

```
  try {
        ListView lv;
    File path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(path);
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.filelist);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> array=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder);
    lv.setAdapter(array);
   }
```

here is get files mathod

```
   public ArrayList<String> GetFiles(String DirectoryPath) {
   ArrayList<String> MyFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
   File f = new File(DirectoryPath);
   f.mkdirs();
   File[] files = f.listFiles();
   for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
       MyFiles.add(files[i].getName());

  return MyFiles;
}
```

Comment: You have to just recall yopur listview when new folder created dear, that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want to follow a more canonical approach by using a Loader which monitors the folder as its data source. 
You could also use a CursorLoader in conjunction with a CursorAdapter, but that's up to you.
You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this peice of code already working:

```
 ListView lv;
 File path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 ArrayList<String> FilesInFolder = GetFiles(path);
 lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.filelist);
 final ArrayAdapter<String> array=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, FilesInFolder);
 lv.setAdapter(array);
```

Now you have the arrayAdapter using your `filesInFolder` array.
In order to refresh the view simply add items to that array the adapter is pointing to and then use the following call:

```
array.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

It'll let the adapter know that its data is now updated with some more data, and it'll redraw the content of the list.

You could also just change a bit your code for updating:

```
public void updateList() {
            File f = new File(DirectoryPath);
            f.mkdirs();
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for (int i=0; i<files.length; i++) 
                    if (!FilesInFolder.contains(files[i].getName())
                        FilesInFolder.add(files[i].getName());
            array.notifyDatasetChanged();
}
```